# for loop not working properly c++

Tags: c++

*The program will ask how many items to store, and then asks for the name of the item and the price.
Finally, all the items must be displayed in a table. Duplicate items must be displayed as one item. Use only small letters.
Display should look like this:*

[image]

My problem #1 is that if an item with its price is equal to another input, the program should count them as 1 and the quantity of an item will depend on how many same input(the item and price).

Problem #2 is that the 1st for loop in the void function does not work properly, it always ask an item and price and doesn't stop, (#3) and the item number too is not working properly. Here's the picture:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int num;




void numItems(int num){
    string items[num];
    double price[num];
    int quantity[num];

    for(int x=0;x<num;x++){

        cout<<"Item #"<<x+1<<": ";
        cin.get();//cin.ignore();
        /*cin>>items[x];*/getline(cin,items[x]);

        cout<<"Price #"<<x+1<<": ";
        cin>>price[x];

        if(x=1){ //(x==1) fixed
            if(items[x]==items[x-1] && price[x]==price[x-1]){
                quantity[x]++;  
            }   
        }
        cout<<"\n\n";
    }

    cout<<"============RECEIPT=============\n\n";

    cout<<"Items\t\t\t\tPrice\t\t\t\tQuantity"<<endl;

    for(int x=0;x<num;x++){
        if(x=1){
            if(items[x]==items[x-1]){
                cout<<items[x]<<"\t\t\t\t"<<price[x]<<"\t\t\t\t"<<quantity<<endl;       
            }else continue;
        }   
    }   
}







int main(){

    cout<<"===ITEM AUDIT==="<<endl;



    cout<<"Enter number of items to store: ";
    cin>>num;
    cout<<"\n\n";

    numItems(num);

}
```

Comment: You wrote `if(x=1){` instead of a double equation sign. A single `=` is the assignment operator in C++, so you set the value of `x` to 1 in every iteration

Comment: Typo.  `if (x = 1)` sets `x` to `1` on every iteration of both loops.   You probably intend `if (x == 1)`.

Comment: `if (x=1)` should be `if (x==1)`. If you only used a debugger...

Comment: Oh sorry. I'll edit that, thanks.

Comment: The only problem now is the RECEIPT. It doesn't output something - here's the picture: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwzP5qGL8d3XVUVBekJMUFkwYm8

Comment: Put this in your `~/.bashrc`: `alias g++="g++ -Wall"`.

Comment: You're only outputting anything if `items[1] == items[0]`.

Comment: @erip - I don't know where to put that. Any guide?

Comment: @erip: `~/.bashrc` on Windows? I don't think so mate!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The question was edited! :( Anyway, come mid-summer, you'll think so!

Comment: @erip: It was not edited in any way that provides more or different information than it did originally

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't look at links. If there's information not provided on this page then either that information is extraneous or the question isn't well-presented. That's neither here nor there.

Comment: @erip: It's everywhere, actually, as your choice to read only part of the information presented led you to make an incorrect suggestion.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Should comments not be taken with a grain of salt? I'm not issuing an edict, I'm making a suggestion. :)

Answer (score 2):

The if statement has a hard-to-spot issue:

```
 if(x=1){
```

should be

```
 if(x == 1) {
```

Don't forget to fix both typos!

Comment: not hard. All compilers gives warnings.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't saw that. Thanks Marinov. The problem left is the #1. The numbers 2 and 3 is fixed by that (x==1). hehe

Comment: @Jacek - Most compilers can be configured to give such warnings, but don't do so by default.

Comment: @JacekCz I agree :) But hard-to-spot in code review, when you are just reading a code through. @Dem: You should use `-pedantic-errors` compiler option and code without errors and warnings - helps a lot!

Comment: @MarinovIván - How can I do that?

Comment: _"But hard-to-spot in code review, when you are just reading a code through"_ I don't know, I spot `=` immediately.